# Angular2: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, typescript, components, embed

I'm starting developing in Angular 2 and cannot understand what's happening and how to solve my problem. Im getting next error:

```
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'public/pdf/null.pdf'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'public/pdf/null.pdf'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59583:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59561:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:47079:31)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4544:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4518:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4544:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4518:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4544:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4518:18)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4544:26)
```

My scenario consist in I have a list of documents, some documents are images and others PDFs, when I click in a PDF document it must show the PDF viewer with the file in their component. Im sending the ID of the document thought the url by the router so Im catching in the component and getting the entire object by http get service. I got the data without problems but when I try to embed in the PDF viewer I get the `EXEPTION` with a `null` data.

This is my PDF component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Doc } from "../../../interfaces/docs";
import { DocService } from "../../../services/documento.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf',
  templateUrl: './pdf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdf.component.css'],
  providers:  [DocService]
})
export class PdfComponent implements OnInit {

public id  : any;
public doc : Doc;
public url : string;
public pdfUrl: any;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _httpService: DocService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)  {
  this.id = route.snapshot.params['id']
}
ngOnInit()  {
  this.doc  = {
    reg: null,
    key:    null,
    name:   null,
    date:    null,
    file:  null,
    type:     null
  };


  this._httpService.searchDoc(this.id)
    .subscribe(
      data  =>  {this.doc= data, console.log(JSON.stringify(data))},
      error =>  alert(error + ' Error GET')
    )

    this.url = '/public/pdf/'+this.doc.file+'.pdf',
    console.log("url "+ this.url),
    this.pdfUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

    console.log("url " +this.url)

}

}
```

this is my HTML from the PDF Component

```
<section>
  <embed  class="center-block" [src]="pdfUrl" width="80%" type='application/pdf'>
  <iframe [src]="pdfUrl" width="500" height="600" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
</section>
```

Note: I have `embed` and `iframe` just to test if it was the label I was trying to test

I'll appreciate any help

Thank you in advance

George

Comment: It looks like the server is configured improperly, and non-existing 'public/pdf/null.pdf' url returns index page. Obviously, this will cause iframe to contain a copy of the app.

Comment: I have no problems with the server... actually Im getting the data from the object without problems but I cannot use outside the ```searchDoc()``` if I call the data from the view using for example ```<h3>{{doc.file}}</h3>``` I see the data without problem but if I try to use it in the ```<ember></ember>``` label it will send me the ```null``` data

Comment: The explanation above is the most reasonable explanation why *Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'public/pdf/null.pdf'* error may appear. Considering this, it is hard to believe that `/public/pdf/null.pdf` url returns pdf and not html file. Please, post what `/public/pdf/null.pdf` reqyest returns if you believe if it's not the issue.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what `searchDoc` does because it sets `this.doc` later. At the moment when `ngOnInit` runs, `url` and `pdfUrl` are equal to `/public/pdf/null.pdf`, iframe requests this src, and the server spoils the things because it returns html file and not 404 for non-existing file.

Comment: hello @estus, I just found my problem and just posted the answer. Thank you for your time, I appreciate. :)

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike can you tell me what the issue is? I have the same problem!